# I am converting some java code to C. Stuck at one line CharAt()

Tags: java, c

I am new. Trying to learn. I assume I am gonna have to create a charat() function myself. or is there a library function that I can look up that is similar (google seemed to indicate so)? Does boolean here function the same in c? I am just learning debugging. like debugging training wheels. I guess I will find out later anyway but thought Id ask. Answers that explain the why of this stuff is eternally more helpful in understanding the differences in the languages. plus I actually just like talking to other humans. even digital ones.

```
while (scan.hasNext())
    {
    r = scan.nextInt();
    c = scan.nextInt();
    star = new char[r + 2][c + 2];
    used = new boolean[r + 2][c + 2];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < r + 1; i++)
        {
        String str = scan.next();
        for (int j = 1; j < c + 1; j++)
            star[i][j] = str.charAt(j - 1);
        }
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int r = 0;
int c = 0;
char[][] star;
boolean[][] used;

void fill(int i , int j) {
    if (i == 0 || i == r + 1 || j == 0 || j == c + 1)
        return;
    
    used[i][j] = true;
    
    if (star[i + 1][j] == '-' && !used[i + 1][j])
        fill (i + 1 , j);
    
    if (star[i - 1][j] == '-' && !used[i - 1][j])
        fill (i - 1 , j);
    
    if (star[i][j + 1] == '-' && !used[i][j + 1])
        fill (i , j + 1);
    
    if (star[i][j - 1] == '-' && !used[i][j - 1])
        fill (i , j - 1);
}
int main(void){

int caseNumber = 1;

  scanf("%d", &r);
  scanf("%d", &c);

  star = new char[r+2][c+2];
  used = new boolean[r+2][c+2];

  for(int i = 1; j < c + 1; i++){
  
   scanf("%s", &str);
  }
  
  count = 0;
  
  for (int i = 1; i < r + 1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < c + 1; j++)
            {
            if (star[i][j] == '-')
                {
                if (!used[i + 1][j] && !used[i - 1][j] && !used[i][j + 1] && !used[i][j - 1])
                    {
                    count++;
                    fill(i , j);
                    }
                }
            }

        printf("Case" + caseNumber + ":" + count);
        caseNumber++;
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: In C there's no `String`, it's a `char array` so your `str.charAt(index)` is just gonna be `str[index]`

Comment: Java is an object language, are you sure you do not want C++ rather than C ?

Comment: @bruno `I assume I am gonna have to create a charat() function myself.`

Comment: okay thank you. I just needed to know the difference in structure. I need this function in c for a program that finds groups of symbols. I know I should know better but this is how I learn. it is a open kattis challenge. trying to not be a script kitty is very difficult. Im definitely past copy pasta but applying what i have learned without example is very challenging

Comment: [tag:c] is a very different language (despite having a somewhat similar grammar). A Java `boolean` is its own data type, in C it's an `int` (see [`stdbool.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html)). In Java it is `true` or `false`, in C it is usually true that `0` is `false` and everything else is `true`. Usually. Older C code had even fewer rules. You must manage your memory in C. You should post the C code if you get stuck and need more help.

Comment: thanks I posted it. with my reasoning